# How to set up multiple query parameters for Imgur API's search endpoints

Tags: api, request, postman, imgur

I'm trying to get the URLs of multiple images using Imgur's [Gallery Search API](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search).

I ran a test of the API using Postman and was able to get a response.
[image]

I then used the `q_size_px` parameter to specify the size of the image to get.

[image]

Status is 200, but I didn't get anything back.

Is there a way to specify multiple parameters for a query?
I want to specify the image size and multiple image types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/gallery#gallery-search :

[image]

SO if you use `q_size_px` it will ignore you `q` parameter

So you cant search for multi type and size in same time, you need to do multiple request for each file extenssion